# Which permissions are required to enable the low-trust authentication model on-premises?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-addin, office-365, administration

Which **permissions** are required to configure the **low-trust** authentication model on-premises? I'll want to use low-trust add-ins on-prem.

There are good resources available for [doing this in PnP](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Scripts/SharePoint.LowTrustACS.Configuration):

> **PowerShell to enable low trust authentication model at on-premises**
>
> This document and scripts explain how to setup low trust
>   authentication between your SharePoint 2013/2016 on-premises farm and
>   an Office 365 tenant.

I'll use the scripts provided there. Cmdlets used by these scripts include:

- `Set-MsolServicePrincipal`
- (well... maybe that's it)

Which permissions are necessary in the **Office 365 tenant** as well as in **Azure AD**? Probably tenant admin something... On-prem probably farm admin. But my focus is on knowing this about the cloud.